# What are all the required details for create Paypal Business Account for my Indian e-comm site

Tags: paypal, magento-1.9, credit-card, visa, mastercard

Actually my site from India, I need to get cash from my international customer by using Paypal.

> What are all the required details for creating India business account?

**`Note: Not for India, only for international customers`.**

Answer (score 0):

You can check these pages on PayPal to create a business account for Indian merchants:

[Get up and running quickly](https://www.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/manage-my-account)

[Accept Payments From Across The World](https://www.paypal.com/in/webapps/mpp/merchant)

If you already have a PayPal account you can login and click the link that says `Upgrade to a Business account` in the bottom left corner under the `Manage your account` section.

To start accepting PayPal in India, you only need a PAN card and a bank account to receive payments in.

I hope these links help

Comment: PAN card is enough for everything, or any other details required?

Comment: USA Paypal account required details like SSN, etc. like what are all the required details need for creating Indian Paypal account for getting the amount from international customers.

Comment: Yes. All you need is a PAN card and a bank account where you would like to receive the payments